# IBM LDAP 6.4 - DB2 10.5: Failed to create database instance to run idsicrt command

Tags: amazon-web-services, db2, ldap, websphere, rhel7

I'm working in RHEL 7.7 (AWS - RHEL-7.7_HVM-20190923-x86_64-0-Hourly2-GP2)

For install Security Directory Server V6.4 I folowed the below [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/installation-procedure-security-directory-server-v64-sles-12-x8664)

And according to this [documentation](https://burgatshow.com/2018/10/28/installing-ibm-security-directory-server-6-4/) for create a SDS instance, it's necessary to run this command:

```
cd /opt/ibm/ldap/V6.4/sbin
./idsicrt -I idsldap -a 3538 -c 3539 -e "EncryptionSeed123" -g "EncSalt12345" -p 389 -s 686
```

But tu run that command, I got the below

```
./idsicrt -I idsldap -a 3538 -c 3539 -e "EncryptionSeed123" -g "EncSalt12345" -p 389 -s 686
GLPWRP123I The program '/opt/ibm/ldap/V6.4/sbin/64/idsicrt' is used with the following arguments 'idsicrt -I idsldap -a 3538 -c 3539 -e ***** -g ***** -p 389 -s 686'.
You have chosen to perform the following actions:

GLPICR020I A new directory server instance 'idsldap' will be created.
GLPICR057I The directory server instance will be created at: '/home/idsldap'.
GLPICR013I The directory server instance's port will be set to '389'.
GLPICR014I The directory server instance's secure port will be set to '686'.
GLPICR015I The directory instance's administration server port will be set to '3538'.
GLPICR016I The directory instance's administration server secure port will be set to '3539'.
GLPICR019I The description will be set to: 'IBM Security Directory Server Instance V6.4'.
GLPICR021I Database instance 'idsldap' will be configured.

Do you want to....
 (1) Continue with the above actions, or
 (2) Exit without making any changes:1


GLPICR028I Creating directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR025I Registering directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR026I Registered directory server instance: : 'idsldap'.
GLPICR049I Creating directories for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR050I Created directories for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR043I Creating key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR044I Created key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR040I Creating configuration file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR041I Created configuration file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR034I Creating schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR035I Created schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR037I Creating log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR038I Created log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR088I Configuring log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR089I Configured log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR085I Configuring schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR086I Configured schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR073I Configuring ports and IP addresses for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR074I Configured ports and IP addresses for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR077I Configuring key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR078I Configured key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR046I Creating profile scripts for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR047I Created profile scripts for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR069I Adding entry to /etc/inittab (if supported) for the administration server for directory instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR070I Added entry to /etc/inittab for the administration server for directory instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR118I Creating runtime executable for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR119I Created runtime executable for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL074I Starting admin server for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL075I Started admin server for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR029I Created directory server instance: : 'idsldap'.
GLPICR031I Adding database instance 'idsldap' to directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL002I Creating database instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL004E Failed to create database instance: 'idsldap'. The failure might have occurred because the system was not set up correctly before using the tool.
GLPICR033E Failed to add database instance 'idsldap' to directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP002I Deleting directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL077I Stopping admin server for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPCTL078I Stopped admin server for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP072I Deleting the runtime executable for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP073I Deleted the runtime executable for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP035I Removing entry from /etc/inittab (if supported) for the admin server for directory server instance 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP036I Removed entry from /etc/inittab for the admin server for directory server instance 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP020I Deleting profile scripts for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP021I Deleted profile scripts for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP011I Deleting log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP012I Deleted log files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP008I Deleting schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP009I Deleted schema files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP014I Deleting configuration file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP015I Deleted configuration file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP017I Deleting key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP018I Deleted key stash files for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP077I Deleting the ldapdb.properties file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP075I Deleted the ldapdb.properties file for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP023I Deleting directories for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP024I Deleted directories for directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP039I Unregistering directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP040I Unregistered directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPIDP003I Deleted directory server instance: 'idsldap'.
GLPICR024W The program did not complete successfully. View earlier error messages for information about the exact error.
```

**I can see the below in the logs file**

```
cat db2icrt_local.log.25909
       Program name = db2idbm
Instance home dir = /home/idsldap,   Sysadm group = idsldap
Instance type = 1,  Auth type = server

DB21015E  The Command Line Processor backend process request queue or input
queue was not created within the timeout period.
Update DBM cfg SYSADM_GROUP errcode = 8
DBI1281E  The database manager configuration file could not be
      initialized.

Explanation:

An error occurred when attempting to initialize the database manager
configuration file. A DB2 instance could not be created or upgraded.

User response:

Refer to the log file for troubleshooting. Resolve the problem and try
the command again. If the problem persists, contact your IBM service
representative.


   Related information:
   Gathering diagnostic information for instance creation problems
```

and

```
at db2icrt.log.23965

DB2 Setup log file started at:  Wed Jan 11 09:17:23 PM 2023 UTC
============================================================

Operating system information: Linux 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64.#1 SMP Tue Jul 26 14:15:37 UTC 2022 x86_64
WARNING: Notification SMTP server has not been specified. Notifications cannot
be sent to contacts in your contact list until this is specified. For more
information see the DB2 administration documentation.



New instances:
    Instance name:                              idsldap
        Instance user information:
            User name:                          idsldap
        Fenced user information:
            User name:                          idsldap





Setting default global profile registry variables :.......Success
The maximum number of logical nodes was not specified for the instance
"idsldap". Default parameters will be used.

Initializing instance list :.......Success
ERROR:        Program name = db2idbm
Instance home dir = /home/idsldap,   Sysadm group = idsldap
Instance type = 1,  Auth type = server

DB21015E  The Command Line Processor backend process request queue or input
queue was not created within the timeout period.
Update DBM cfg SYSADM_GROUP errcode = 8
DBI1281E  The database manager configuration file could not be
      initialized.

Explanation:

An error occurred when attempting to initialize the database manager
configuration file. A DB2 instance could not be created or upgraded.

User response:

Refer to the log file for troubleshooting. Resolve the problem and try
the command again. If the problem persists, contact your IBM service
representative.


   Related information:
   Gathering diagnostic information for instance creation problems


ERROR: An error occurred while configuring the instance "idsldap".

Configuring DB2 instances :.......Failure
Updating global profile registry :.......Success

Post-installation instructions
-------------------------------

Required steps:
There were some errors detected during DB2 installation. To collect the information files from the system, run the "db2support -install" command with the proper options before reporting the problem to IBM service. For information regarding the usage of the db2support tool, check the DB2 Information Center.

DB2 Text Search has not been configured for the instance "idsldap".To automatically configure DB2 text search services, run the db2iupdt command (orthe db2nrupdt command for non-root installations) specifying the -j "TEXT_SEARCH" option.Manual configuration steps can be found in the DB2 Text Search documentation "http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/t0052968.html".

Optional steps:
To validate your installation files, instance, and database functionality, run the Validation Tool, /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/bin/db2val. For more information, see "db2val" in the DB2 Information Center.

Open First Steps by running "db2fs" using a valid user ID such as the DB2 instance owner's ID. You will need to have DISPLAY set and a supported webbrowser in the path of this user ID.

Verify that you have access to the DB2 Information Center based on the choices you made during this installation. If you performed a typical or a compact installation, verify that you can access the IBM Web site using the internet. If you performed a custom installation, verify that you can access the DB2 Information Center location specified during the installation.

Ensure that you have the correct license entitlements for DB2 products and features installed on this machine. Each DB2 product or feature comes with a license certificate file (also referred to as a license key) that is distributed on an Activation CD, which also includes instructions for applying the license file. If you purchased a base DB2 product, as well as, separately priced features, you might need to install more than one license certificate. The Activation CD for your product or feature can be downloaded from Passport Advantage if it is not part of the physical media pack you received from IBM. For more information about licensing, search the Information Center (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp) using terms such as "license compliance", "licensing" or "db2licm".

To use your DB2 database product, you must have a valid license. For information about obtaining and applying DB2 license files, see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0061199.html.


DB2 Setup log file finished at:  Wed Jan 11 09:49:38 PM 2023 UTC
============================================================
```

**Looks like that something was wrong in the DB2 installation but running the validation I got that was successful**

```
./db2val
DBI1379I  The db2val command is running. This can take several minutes.

DBI1335I  Installation file validation for the DB2 copy installed at
      /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5 was successful.

DBI1343I  The db2val command completed successfully. For details, see
      the log file /tmp/db2val-230111_215409.log.
```

I'll appreciate any recommendations

Thanks

Create a SDS LDAP server instance

Comment: To find the immediate cause, you must carefully examine the detail log file that the instance-creation tool created (this is usually in /tmp). You should also edit your question to specify if the Db2 was installed as root or nonroot.  You should also verify that your Db2-server is at the final fixpack level of v10.5 (now out of support), and you should verify that the `db2prereqcheck` tool reported no issues.

Comment: Hi, I added the logs in the post, the failure is to configure the D2 instance and I beleve that it's confirm that the problem is db2. also, D2B and all software configuration was created using root, and finally, I ran ./db2prereqcheck nad looks like it falling to find some packages. thanks you, that last part was very helpful

Comment: Correction:  I ran ./db2prereqcheck and and I can see the below "The db2prereqcheck utility has confirmed that all installation prerequisites were met." for Version "10.5.0.0". Operating system "Linux". i'm not using the DB2 pureScale Feature

Comment: it is unwise to use fixpack-0 of any IBM database product. Before you do anything else, download and install the Fixpack-11 of the V10.5 product. Get an experienced DBA to help if you lack the skills.  Also, before installing Db2, verify that hostname is pingable (ping $(hostname), and DNS is configured, nslookup $(hostname), and verify the hostname matches the /etc/hosts entry.

Comment: for info, Db2 v10.5.0.0 released 2013,  but  RHEL 7.7 released August 2019. The fiinal fixpack of Db2 v10.5 is fixpack 11, released March-2020 so it is much more likely to have any RHEL 7.7 issues resolved, as compared to fixpack-0  (the GA version).

Comment: Hi all. The issue was resolved installing the lates fix packeges11, and adding (Instance_IP HOSTNAME) in the hosts files on /etc/hosts. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing Db2 v10.5.0.11 (the final fixpack for Db2 v10.5)
and also by ensuring that the `/etc/hosts` entry for the hostname is correct, allowing the hostname to be both pingable and allowing nslookup to resolve the hostname.